# require explanation if user changed radiobutton between pageload and postback?

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist, customvalidator

In my form, someone may make a radio button choice today, but change their mind tomorrow, come back, and make a different radio button choice. If so, they need to explain why they decided to make this change, typing their rationale into a text field.

Is there any way for a CustomValidator on the text field to know the RadioButtonList's choice when the page was loaded, in order to compare it to that same RadioButtonList's choice when the page is submitted?

All of this takes place within a FormView, so worst case scenario, I can use the FormView's ItemUpdating event to look at oldvalues and newvalues, and show/hide a label, but this seemed a little hacky, and I'm wondering if there's a pure validator way to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using hidden fields to bind the initial values of the RadioButtonLists. My CustomValidator used the hidden fields for the "before" values and the current SelectedValue of the RadioButtonLists for "after" values.